# View Model recebendo valores Null

Tags: c#

Após um consulta no BD, minha query retorna alguns valores null em alguns atributos e na hora de passar os valores para o model:

```
ViewModel.Participantes.Add(new RelParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM { 
  RA = p.RA.Value, Nome = p.Nome, Modulo = p.Modulo.Value 
});
```

Recebo essa mensagem de erro:

> O objeto nulo deve ter um valor

Como faço para que meu model possa receber valores null ou substituir o null por um valor default?

Comment: Só alterar sua query para retornar um valor default caso seja nulo.

Comment: como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seria bom você deixar claro quais atributos não podem receber null, mas enfim, dependendo do tipo do atributo você pode declarar ele como nullable algo do tipo:

```
public int? RA { get;set; }
```

ou fazer um tratamento para receber um valor caso o retorno do banco seja nulo:

```
RA = p.RA.Value == null ? "valor default" : p.RA.Value;
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!